Improving transaction reception speed on a private RPC
I am running my own private RPC node with the Geyser plugin and Jito Shred Stream. I am monitoring some token accounts, and sometimes the transactions involving the token accounts I am watching are delayed for reasons I have not been able to determine.
I am logging the transaction handling timestamp (with milliseconds), and there is almost a ~1-second difference between the network's timestamp and when I handle it.
I know that transaction timestamps do not have millisecond precision. Let me provide an example to clarify:
Let's say a transaction occurred on the network at 12:00:00. According to my logs, I handled it at 12:00:01.750. Even if the transaction happened at the last millisecond of 12:00:00, it is still almost 750 ms delayed, which is equivalent to nearly 2 block times.
I would like to know what areas could be improved to reduce this delay.
I have been monitoring the server for a long time everything seems normal. no iowait, no swap usage, or memory congestion, cpu usage is around %50.
hw specs:

AMD EPYC 9274F 24-Core Processor (performance mode)
512 gig of ram
2x4 tb nvm ledger and accounts are in separate disks.
up to 5gbps connection

